# Is there an analogous function to generate_array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Here's my query for reference:

```
with weekly_periods as (
  select ticket_id,
         start_time_in_minutes_from_week,
         raw_delta_in_minutes,
         schedule_id,
         week_number,
         greatest(0, start_time_in_minutes_from_week - week_number * (7*24*60)) as ticket_week_start_time,
         least(start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes - week_number * (7*24*60), (7*24*60)) as ticket_week_end_time
  from ticket_solved_time, unnest(generate_array(0, floor((start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes) / (7*24*60)), 1)) as week_number
)
```

I have tried generate_series and also the array functions, but I am not too familiar with the PostgreSQL syntax.

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question, right? The function is called `generate_series` in PostgreSQL. What is it that you are trying to do? Please provide sample input data and expected output.

Comment: Did you tried just `... from ticket_solved_time, generate_series(0, floor((start_time_in_minutes_from_week + raw_delta_in_minutes) / (7*24*60)), 1) as week_number`? Note that the step value 1 is default in this case so it could be omitted.

Comment: I have tried exactly that and it causes an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like below in PostgreSQL to generate random integer array for example

```
select array_agg(round(random() * (max - min)) + min) 
from generate_series(0, elements)
```

Note: [generate_series function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-srf.html) has many signatures that allow you to control what you will get out